# Can't login to Django admin panel

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Made custom user, made custom user manager, can't log in into Django admin panel
[image]

Tried (means don't offer it):

- manage.py synced
- manage.py createsuperuser
- checked that my users actually is staff and active
- set AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS to 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
- set AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

DB - postgres, im also using rest framework

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models, transaction


# Create your models here.
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """

    def create_user(self, deviceId, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not deviceId:
            raise ValueError('The device id must be set')

        user = self.model(deviceId=deviceId, **extra_fields)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, deviceId, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self.create_user(deviceId, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    deviceId = models.TextField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_column='device_id')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='name')
    fcmToken = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, db_column='fcm_token')
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='UserAvatars', null=True)
    pictureUrl = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, db_column='picture_url')

    emailToken = models.TextField(max_length=255, db_column='email_token', blank=True, null=True)
    appleId = models.TextField(max_length=255, db_column='apple_id', blank=True, null=True)
    googleId = models.TextField(max_length=255, db_column='google_id', blank=True, null=True)
    facebookId = models.TextField(max_length=255, db_column='facebook_id', blank=True, null=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'deviceId'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return self

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: I'm strongly in doubt that your custom user model will be able to authenticate against 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', because this backend was specifically created to serve the built-in Django User model. It might be that you will need a custom authentication backend. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't handle the password properly in your `create_user` method. Passwords are obviously supposed to be hashed. when you write `self.model(deviceId=deviceId, **extra_fields)` you are simply setting the **plain text** value received from the user as the password!

When one tries to authenticate Django hashes the password received and tries to match that with the value in the database, which for you will obviously fail. As a reference check [this particular line [Github code]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d828beb68f6b925217242e8f4faac2216f7c9c57/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L145) which is how the password is set in the builtin user model.

To fix this you would have to change your `create_user` and `create_superuser` method like so:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


def create_user(self, deviceId, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a User with the given email and password.
    """
    if not deviceId:
        raise ValueError('The device id must be set')

    user = self.model(deviceId=deviceId, **extra_fields)
    user.password = make_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

def create_superuser(self, deviceId, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
    """
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
    return self.create_user(deviceId, password, **extra_fields)
```

> **Note**: Also don't set `max_length=255` for the password. No matter how long a password is provided only 128 characters are going to be
> stored in the database due to hashing. So you should be setting
> `max_length=128` on the password field.

Comment: Does user.set_password(password) help?